# Docker containers unable to reach each other. Getting CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I am new to Docker but here's what I want to do. Have a create-react-app and node API server

Both are different folders "client" and "server".

I have Dockerfiles for both and docker-compose.yml at the root of project.

Now when I run docker-compose up and try to reach API server from React I get CONNECTION REFUSED  error.

Can anyone help me on this ? React App is running on 3000 & API Server is running on 9040

Here are the DockerFiles and docker-compose files

**Dockerfile of React**

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "run", "frontend"]
```

Dockerfile of Node/Express API

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9040

CMD ["yarn", "run", "backend"]
```

Docker Compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  wt-client:
    image: sriram2207/wt-client
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - wt-app
  wt-server:
    image: sriram2207/wt-server
    ports:
      - "9040:9040"
    networks:
      - wt-app
networks:
  wt-app:
    driver: bridge
```

All I want to do is run both containers with one single command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of connecting via `localhost:9040`, try connecting via `wt-server:9040`

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm. Can you explain why though ?

Comment: Each service is running in a separate container, with their own network, hence you cannot connect to them via localhost. You can connect to them conveniently via service name. Another way is to use `network_mode: host` https://docs.docker.com/network/host/